# Is the next middleware called synchronously when the next function is called in Node Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to understand how the `next` function works in Node Express framework. I understand we use the next function in the current middleware to invoke the next middleware that we have mentioned. middlewares are nothing but callback functions passed to `express.use/[METHOD]()`.

---

When we call next(), is the `next` middleware called synchronously? i.e does the next middleware run in the same process tick, or does the next middleware gets queued in the callback or microtask queue and is run at some later point of time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the next middleware is called synchronously.
They are running in the same process queue, it is working like a stack.
You can find more informations [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Thank you, but could you please point out in the docs where it exactly mentions it is synchronous. I have this doubt because we can make middlewares asynchronous by setting it as async

Answer (score 0):

As Matthieu BRAULT mentioned, `next` calls the following middleware and its code runs synchronously. This can be proven by using the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tick-id. Here, we will get different numbers if we are on on different ticks.